# Solving for x in a mod relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How do I approach the problem: $$7^{95} \equiv x^3\text{(mod 10)}$$ when solving for $x$?

Comment: 7 and 10 are very small numbers. Work out $7, 7^2, 7^3, 7^4, 7^5, \dots$ mod 10, and see if you can spot a pattern. Or even just notice that $7^2 = -1$, so $7^4 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $7$ is a primitive root. Writing $x =7^n$,

$$7^{95} \equiv 7^{3n}(\bmod10)$$ is equivalent to $$95 \equiv 3n (\bmod 4)$$ so $$n \equiv 1 (\bmod 4)$$ and $x = 7$.

Comment: I guess we should note: $x$ is a unit mod $10$, since $x^3 = 7^{95}$ is.